# Split String Using Regex in c#

Tags: regex

I have a file with the following content

```
aaaaa(fasdfiojasdlfkj)
213.df(fasdfsadffdfsd)
53434534535(oipowerier)
2.3.*12.4(asdfrwer)
```

i would like to have a list like this eventually,

```
List<string[]> sList = new List<string[]>();
sList[0] = new string[]{"aaaaa", "fasdfiojasdlfkj"};
sList[1] = new string[]{"213.df", "fasdfsadffdfsd"};
sList[2] = new string[]{"53434534535", "oipowerier"};
sList[3] = new string[]{"2.3.*12.4", "asdfrwer"};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this without regex:

```
var result = stringlist.ConvertAll(x =>x.Split(new char[] {'(',')'},
                           StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't need `Regex` for this - [`string.Split`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx) will be enough.

If you use it *per* line:

```
List<string[]> sList = new List<string[]>();
foreach(var line in fileLines)
{
    sList.Add(line.Split(new Char[]{ '(', ')'}, 
              StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<string[]> sList = new List<string[]>();

MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(yourtext, @"([^\(]+)\(([^\)]+)\)");

foreach(Match mymatches in matches)
{

    //get the data
    string firststring = mymatches.Groups[1].Value;
    string secondstring = mymatches.Groups[2].Value;

    sList.Add(new string[] {firststring, secondstring});
}
```

not tested though....